# É possível alternar entre JDKs no Netbeans trabalhando em um projeto Maven web?

Tags: java, netbeans, ide, jdk

Estou trabalhando com o `java7` mas agora tenho outros projetos `Maven web`que foram construídos para a plataforma `java8`, estou usando `Netbeans` 8.0.2. Antes quando criava apenas o projeto java web (não Maven), eu tenho duas `JDK`s ,7 e 8 devidamente instaladas, podia clicar com botão do mouse sobre o projeto ir em propriedades e escolher a plataforma para o projeto normalmente. Quando tento fazer o mesmo com um projeto `Maven web` não consigo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você não está conseguindo alternar entre as plataformas porque provavelmente só existe uma definida nas configurações do IDE.

O [@DiegoFelipe](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/28595) sugeriu uma forma de resolver, mas além dessa é possível também incluir e/ou remover plataformas diretamente pelo IDE. No menu superior existe a opção ***Ferramentas***, dentro há outra chamada ***Plataformas Java***:

<kbd>[image: ferramentas > plataformas java]</kbd>

Acessando essa opção será possível gerenciar as plataformas existentes.
Para adicionar uma nova basta clicar em <kbd>Adicionar Plataforma...</kbd> e selecionar o diretório (local ou remoto) em que encontra-se o JDK.

[image: plataformas java]

Depois disso você já conseguirá alternar normalmente entre as plataformas acessando as propriedades de qualquer projeto Java.

---

Em projetos Maven, para alterar o JDK, clique com o botão direito sobre o nome do projeto e na guia ***Compilar*** estão as opções de plataformas existentes — e o botão <kbd>Gerenciar Plataformas Java...</kbd> que vai levá-lo a mesma janela que expliquei acima.

[image: compilar]

---

Se ainda precisar alterar **o formato do código fonte**, acesse as propriedades do projeto e na aba ***Códigos-fonte***, altere o formato do código fonte para 1.8 se estiver escrevendo em Java8:

[image: códigos-fonte]

Comment: Obrigado pela atenção!Mesmo em um projeto Maven web? Eu acho que eu já fiz isso !! E ele não mudou não!!

Comment: Já fiz a mudança através do etc netbeans.conf !! Nesse seu exemplo é facil trocar de IDE sem problemas, tente fazer o mesmo com um projeto Maven web!

Comment: Para a mudança de plataforma com java se não tem erro é desse jeito que você ensinou, mas eu quero mudança de plataforma para  um projeto Maven web !!

Comment: Editei mais uma vez, se não for isso... nem imagino qual seja sua dúvida.

Comment: É isso mesmo, obrigado pela paciência  cara!! Só  mais uma coisinha quando clico  no projeto com o botão direito não exste a opção compilar, tem a opção Definir Configuração e depois em Personalizar e só depois existe  guia Compilar .

Comment: É isso mesmo, obrigado pela paciência  cara!! Só  mais uma coisinha quando clico  no projeto com o botão direito não exste a opção compilar, tem a opção Definir Configuração e depois em Personalizar e só depois existe  guia Compilar .

Comment: Não se preocupe mais !! Já deu tudo certo amigo!! Sua resposta ajudou muito!! Um abraço!! O brigado por tudo!

Answer (score 1):

É possivel alterar a versão do JDK no netbeans, pelo arquivo `netbeans.conf`, que se encontra na pasta `C:\Program Files\NetBeans 8.0.2\etc`, caso seu netbeans seja x86, a pasta será `C:\Program Files(x86)\NetBeans 8.0.2\etc`.

Procure a linha `netbeans_jdkhome` e altere conforme endereço do JDK, geralmente é `C:/Program Files/jdk<versao>`, ou caso seja uma versão x86(32 bits) do `jdk`, estará em `C:/Program Files(x86)/jdk<versao>`

Aqui segue um link onde você pode ler como fazer isso [Alterando a JDK padrão no NetBeans](https://spitzergeek.wordpress.com/2010/11/09/alterando-a-jdk-padrao-no-netbeans/).

Comment: Só existe essa possibilidade?

Comment: @PenaPintada normalmente versões mais novas são compatíveis com recursos de versões mais antigas, se seu projeto está como versão 8 ,creio que não haja problemas.

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta!Só existe essa possibilidade, não existiria uma outra,parecido com o que eu fazia antes?

Comment: O que acntece é o seguinte: eu tenho como default a jk7 e o projeto requer o jk8 que já esta  instalado na máquina!! Acho que sua resposta seja o único meio

Comment: @PenaPintada faça a alteração do post que funcionará todos os recursos do jdk 8 normalmente em seu netbeans, apenas lembre-se de efetuar a mudança com ele fechado.

Comment: ! Obrigado pela atenção!! Sim farei isso!!